# Set default date Html.jQuery().DatePicker()

Tags: c#, jquery-ui

```
<td colspan="2"><% Html.jQuery().DatePicker()
                        .Name("birth_date")
                        .DateFormat("dd-mm-yy")
                        .MaximumValue(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-15))
                        .MinimumValue(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100))
                        .NavigationAsDateFormat(true)
                        .Value(Model.birth_date)
                        .Render(); %></td>
```

by default it shows 01-01-001, I want to set the default date.

Comment: I think `Model.birth_date` has the MinDate Value, so maybe add a check there and set the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Model.birth_date` value, its default value may be is `DateTime.MinDate`. So, that's why it shows `01-01-001`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%Model.birth_date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-15) ;  %>
```

This got me the desired result